# yii2 gridview actioncolumn id missing

Tags: url, gridview, yii2

The actioncolumns of my listview doesn't show their detail views. It is not possible to view, update or delete items from my listview. Every view ends up with

Bad Request Error (#400)

Missing required parameters: id

When I take a closer look on the actioncolumn items, I can see that in the url of the view/edit/delete icon, there is no id available. For e.g.

.../index.php?r=opportunities%2Fview

usually is has to be

.../index.php?r=opportunities%2Fview&id=2

The function of my controller is standard:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new OpportunitiesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

The results in the gridview are ok. What happens, why are the ids missing in the actioncolumns? What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

The problem to this situation has been found.

The PrimaryKey flag in the related table 'Opportunities' was missing. It seems that one of the consequences for this purpose are the missing ids in the actioncolumn of the gridview.